# Why can't I catch this 'Maximum Nested Function' Exception in PHP?

Tags: php, function, exception, nested, try-catch

I am experiencing an Exception due to a recursive function in my code, due to the nature of what I am coding, the exception can just be ignored and FALSE returned instead. So here is som simplified code to illustrate my issue.

```
function recursive() {
  try{ recursive(); }
  catch(Exception $e)
  { echo "Error Caught!"; }
}
recursive();
```

I can't seem to catch the 'Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!' exception.
Have I misunderstood how try-catch's work?

Comment: Is it an `exception`? I thought that it was an `error`, and a `fatal error` at that; so unless you have an error handler that can convert fata errors to exceptions, then it can't be caught

Comment: I'm not an expert for PHP, so I don't know if this applies. But maybe the optimizer turned the recursion into a loop because if not taking the exception into account, the recursion is a tail recursion and therefore can be last-call optimized, which turns it into a loop.

Comment: Yeah I think Mark has it, I had no idea errors couldn't be caught like this.

Comment: Errors and Exceptions are very different; and while exceptions can be caught, errors can't.... it's possible to convert some errors to exceptions with a custom [error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), but fatal errors can't be trapped in any way by PHP because they are fatal

Comment: According to 'Philip' in the user notes section of http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php There is a work around to capture fatal errors.

Comment: By all means try it, and throw an exception from your error handler; but I've never seen any evidence that fatal errors can actually be trapped and managed cleanly in the currently available versions of PHP; and using a shutdown function would not allow code execution to continue.... note that (if you can get it to work) function as you've coded it would catch and display the message at every single level of recursion

Comment: Yeah I couldn't actually recover from the error. Funnily enough it was easier for me just to fix what was causing the exception rather than capturing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a Fatal Error and not an Exception so you can not use try & catch.

An Error in general means that the execution of the program by all means can not be continued and has to be aborded.

An Exception on the other hand is like a warning, meaning something has gone wrong, but with the right handling of this exception the program execution can continue.

An Example for try & catch could be:
try to connect to the database ... function connect throws an exception because database server is not reachable ... you catch the exception and decide, well then lets read the stuff from a cached file. The intention behind exception is, to let the developer decide wether he wants to catch the exception and continue the program execution or suspend it.

Answer (score 0):

"PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"

It is a "Fatal error", not an exception. There is no way in PHP to convert it to Exception using set_error_handler (which is good for converting lower level errors to exceptions).

In case of "Fatal error" the only thing You can do is to make some cleanup using register_shutdown_function where you can call error_get_last and recognize that this particular fatal error occured. But thats all You can do, there is no way to continue designed program flow.

BTW this partical fatal error can happen only when You have XDebug module enabled in Your php.ini.